# d3: will selection.style('font-size') always return a value in px?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

The docs just say that [selection.style](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_style) returns the "current computed value".

I tried specifying an element's font-size in css using `rem`s, and `style('font-size')` seems to return the corresponding size in px (e.g. `'10.2px'`).

Is this a behaviour I can rely on across browsers and no matter what units the font-size is specified in in css?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For answering your question, let's have a look at `selection.style` source code:

```
export default function(name, value, priority) {
    var node;
    return arguments.length > 1
      ? this.each((value == null
            ? styleRemove : typeof value === "function"
            ? styleFunction
            : styleConstant)(name, value, priority == null ? "" : priority))
      : defaultView(node = this.node())
          .getComputedStyle(node, null)
          .getPropertyValue(name);
}
```

As you can see, it indeed uses `getComputedStyle`.

Reading the MDN documentation about [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle), we can read that:

> The values returned by getComputedStyle are known as resolved values. These are usually the same as the CSS 2.1 computed values, but for some older properties like width, height or padding, they are instead the used values.

Then, jumping to the documentation about [computed values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/computed_value), we can read that:

> The computation needed to reach the computed value for the property typically involves converting **relative values** (such as those in em units or percentages) to **absolute values**. (emphases mine)

Therefore, since `getComputedStyle` is supported (basic) by Chrome, Edge, Firefox, Internet Explorer, Opera and Safari, we can say that the answer to your question (*"Is this a behaviour I can rely on across browsers?"*) seems to be **yes**.

Comment: Technically there are [other absolute length units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length#Absolute_length_units) than just px, like `mm` and `pt`. Though it seems unlikely they would actually enter into the picture.

Comment: @Gerardo You might want to revisit your answer since the behaviour differs for versions 4.9+ as was brought to our attention by [*"d3.js v4.9 Get the calculated width of selected element"*](/q/44017721). On the other hand does even the question quote obsolete documentation. I think at least a little note of caution would be helpful for both posts.

Comment: Yes, i saw that, and also the new `d3.style()`.

Comment: your answer is right - `...("Is this a behaviour I can rely on across browsers?") seems to be yes.`. But if you go here [computed_values inheritance](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/cascade.html#inheritance), you'll see that the specification defines also `pt` computed values. I tested the example in FF (114) and it still returns `px` instead of `pt`. As you wrote - `getComputedStyle` returns `px` always, but this is not as specified by W3C. Does someone know why is that?